# Can the administrator account on my child’s laptop be removed remotely by my child’s old school?

Tags: remote-desktop

We moved from Melbourne CBD area 3.5 hours away into Gippsland and I brought my sons laptop just at end of last year (the only one allowed at his school for $1,200 AUD) and now he needs it for his new school.

His old school has said I need to bring back the laptop so they can remove the administrator but with all the lockdown restrictions in place, this has not been possible.

Any ideas on other options or can they remotely remove it?

Comment: My first impulse would be if simply mailing the laptop back to the old school is at all possible. That seems like the easiest thing to do. And yes, the laptop is gone for a few days — or perhaps a week? — while this is done, but it costs less than delivering it in person.

Comment: Knowing precisely what the laptop is, what OS is on it & what management software/structure would perhaps help.

Comment: sounds like it's *your* laptop and not theirs. This is kinda totalitarian that they want to be the administrator on your laptop instead of you..

Comment: You are also dealing with the expertize of the admin.  They know how to do it one way and you have to live within their expertize!